# Random Number Game and Removing Numbers

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm trying to create a random number game in Python which the computer starts by giving a random number from 1 to 10 and then consecutively, the computer and the user can remove a few numbers. The person that removes the last number to 0 loses.

An example of the output that I imagine is like this:

```
The starting number is: 5
computer removes: 3
2 numbers are left
User removes: 1
1 number is left
computer removes 1
user wins!
```

What functions can I use to perform the removing task?

Comment: You can use `-` to subtract two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import random
random.randint(0, 10)
```

to create a random integer and assign it to a variable. And the same function to subtract a random value.

You can use `input()` to ask a user for their input.